# Inputfield Value into Variable

Tags: visualforce

I have a picklist field.  When a user select an Account I would like to store it in a variable (Account_Name).  How can this be done?

This is what I have:

```
 <apex:pageBlockSection title="Account Selection">
    <apex:inputField value="{!Acct.Accounts__c}"/>    
 </apex:pageblocksection>

//apex class

 public String Account_Name_v{get;set;}
```

Comment: On a Visualforce page? Can you post what your page looks like thus far?

Comment: How do people add snippet of their codes on this board?  Sorry, I'm new.

Comment: use the button that is a pair of Brackets   {}.  Highlight the code, and then hit that brackets button to format the code

Comment: Shortcut... Highlight the code, press Ctrl-K, it'll block it up for you correctly.

Comment: @caky Is your controller standard or extension controller?

Comment: Thank you everyone.  I'm on to the next step of creating my first VF page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only use `<apex:inputField>` tags with fields on proper SObjects. When you want to save information to a controller member variable instead you must use one of the more specific alternatives. You can create a picklist of available values and then write it back to your member variable by specifying it as the value of the `<apex:selectList>` tag.

```
<apex:pageBlockSection title="Account Selection">
    <apex:selectList value="{!Account_Name_v}">
        <apex:selectOptions value="{!options}"/>
    </apex:selectList>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
```

Since this is in a page block section you're probably after standard formatting, in which case you'll want to wrap this input element inside an `<apex:pageBlockSectionItem>` tag along with a label like so:

```
<apex:pageBlockSection title="Account Selection">
    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
        <apex:outputLabel for="acctName"/>
        <apex:selectList value="{!Account_Name_v}" id="acctName"
            <apex:selectOptions value="{!options}"/>
        </apex:selectList>
    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
```

**Controller**

```
public List<SelectOption> GetOptions()
{
    // You could populate this using a query for accounts
    List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>
    {
        new SelectOption('acct1', 'Account One'),
        new SelectOption('acct2', 'Account Two'),
        new SelectOption('acct3', 'Account Three')
    };

    return options;
}
```

Comment: LaceySnr, you're the best.  This is my first VF page and you've answered all of my questions I've posted. I really like and find it extremely helpful reading your snippet of codes.  Thanks

Comment: Hi LaceySnr,  I hoping that you can help with one problem.  I'm trying to pass a variable into my SOQL statement.  So, I've model my code as you shown above. Here is my SOQL Statement: `{List<Design_Activity__c> Designs=[select MMBT_Account__r.ID, MMBT_Account__r.Name,Calendar_Month__c,  Calendar_Year__c from Object__c Where MMBT_Account__r.Name =:Account_Name_v and Calendar_Month__r.Month__c = 'September' Limit 5];}`

Comment: It doesn't seem that the value from the user selection is being pass down to the variable Account_Name_v.  The result for this query is blank.  But if I replace the Account_Name_v with an actual account name such as 'First Horizon' then I would the right result.

Comment: Is the account name reset in the getter or anywhere? I've had issues with those being called before the action method is invoked.

Comment: Then it should definitely have a value in the method with a query. I'd check for conflicting variable names (i.e. a local superceeding the member variable) and that the value chosen definitely matches the field on the record.

Comment: I think I know what problem is.  It is my rendering section of my VF code.  To this test, Do you know how I can set a default selection to the account?  Thanks

Comment: Yeah, just set the variable to the account you want to default to. In `GetOptions()` you could just do `Account_Name_v = options[0].GetValue();`.

Comment: Resolved, it is a rerender issue.

Comment: Capturing the user inputs by using the Selection option was hard coded.  How would I do this dynamically?  Most likely if the user start to type in the Account name there would be a drop down menu with selections.  Thanks